# Total number of lead generated in report salesforce

Tags: report-chart

I created a summary report which shows details of lead as shown in below fig.
[image]

No. of Lead and No. of Status Converted column are custom summary formula.

As my requirement is i need to only show Lead Status equals closed converted and No. of Lead equals total number of all Lead record are inserted.

Is it possible to do this any way???
Any idea, any solution...any help will be grateful...

Currently No. of Lead are getting correct but as i tried to filter Lead Status equals Closed - Converted then No. of lead values getting wrong as shown in below fig.

Here as per example i need No.of lead value equal 53 instead of 24,17 instead of 9.
[image]

Any solution how to get correct value will be helpful...
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Diepn! Does my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dipen!

You can go for a **Joined Report** and achieve your functionality. Joined Report gives you **flexibility to have different set of data together** and bring out a **comparison between them**.

You can **add one report type only once** so you need to create a custom Lead report type to pull the same data twice in your joined report and put the required filter on second set of data.

Look at the following screenshots and let me know if the solution is clear to you.

[image: Custom Report Type - To pull the same data again]
[image: Report Builder]
[image: Output]

Here the custom summary formulas I used in both the blocks just contain the record count. Even this formula is not required it will display the record count by itself.

Additionally if required you can also add a cross block formulas and calculate the ratio or percentage.

[image: Enhanced Report]

Thank You.